# Can i install Joomla extensions without using joomla backend

Tags: php, joomla

Is there any way i can install joomla extensions by just uploading files and manually insert things in database using xml file.

i mean what joomla does in backend , i want to do that using shell script

Comment: Sure, there's no reason you couldn't figure out what Joomla's doing in the database to enable modules and mimic it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly coded extensions will have an SQL file that can be run through your DB manager. The rest of the files need to be uploaded to the proper location. It's pretty simple really.

Comment: I am checking and few of them don't have any sql file . Is there any source where i can see how joomla actually installs extensions , ii mean each and every step

Comment: @Mosquito : find the file `JoomlaRoot => libraries => joomla => installer => installer.php` and find the function `install()`

Comment: If they don't have an SQL file then they don't make any modifications to the database, you should be able to simply upload the files.